# How to set dynamic attributes in React Input Component from json props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have used the reusable input component and sending JSON attributes as props to the input component When I am using it in the component it is showing only one attribute from JSON array.

In form:

```
             <InputField value={allValues.new_password}
                  name="new_password"
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Enter New Password"
                  required={true}
                  id="new_password"
                  onChange={handleChange("new_password")}
                  attributes={[
                    {
                      name: "data-parsley-equalto",
                      value: "#confirm_password"
                    },
                    {
                      name: "data-parsley-errors-container",
                      value: "#password-errors"
                    }
                  ]}
                />
```

In Input Component

```
      for (let i = 0; i < props.attributes.length; i++) {
        var attr_name = props.attributes[i].name;
        var attr_value = props.attributes[i].value;
        setAttributes({
          ...attributes,
          [attr_name]: "" + attr_value + ""
        });
      }
    }
```

```
        <input
          type={type}
          value={value}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name={name}
          id={id}
          required={required}
          {...attributes}
        />
```

When I check it is showing only one attribute

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Confirm password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" required="" value="" data-parsley-errors-container="#confirm_password-errors">
```

Does anyone help me with what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed equality to the iterated attriubtue in loop;

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= props.attributes.length; i++) {
...
```

Comment: I don't think there is a problem.

Comment: @MeghrajShiradwade, did you try it? I mean the loop without equality just won't return the last attribute in array.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. We have only two elements. 0th index and 1st index.  So less than condition is okay.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to concatenate previous states with useState hook, you should pass a "prev" argument to the function and use that instead of the prop name:

```
setAttributes({
  ...attributes,
  [attr_name]: "" + attr_value + ""
});
```

should be this instead:

```
setAttributes(prevState => {
  ...prevState,
  [attr_name]: "" + attr_value + ""
});
```